# select two columns from two different tables in the same db using mysql + use the output of query in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

**Dear Friends**,

i want to select two columns from two different tables in the same db using mysql and set the output of the query to a variable in c#.

**currently my code is as shown below:**

```
MySqlCommand logcmdCheck = new MySqlCommand(query, connectionCheck);

string query = "SELECT DB.table1.column1,DB.table1.column2,DB.table2.column1,DB.table2.column2,DB.table2.column3 FROM DB.table1 WHERE DB.table1.column1=?x,DB.table2 WHERE DB.table2.column1=?y";

logcmdCheck.Parameters.AddWithValue("?x",UserName);
logcmdCheck.Parameters.AddWithValue("?y",emailID);

MySqlDataReader ldr = logcmdCheck.ExecuteReader();

A = ldr[0].ToString();

B = ldr[1].ToString();

C = ldr[2].ToString();

D = ldr[3].ToString();

E = ldr[4].ToString();
```

**Error**: Mysql query syntax is wrong.

Kindly please help me out with the mysql command to perform the requirement.

Thanks in advance

Suraj

Comment: I suggest looking at the syntax for doing joins http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to use a SQL Join. Check it out here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp. You need to have a foreign key in one of the tables that allows you to connect to the primary key of the other table. Every good database should be set up with tables that have foreign keys.

For example:

```
    Table 1:
          OrderNumber     Name         Order Total
          1               John Smith   10.00
          2               Sally Smith  5.00
          3               Berry Jones  25.00 

    Table 2:
          Item Number     ItemTotal    OrderNumber
          1               5.00         1
          2               5.00         1
          3               2.50         2
          4               2.50         2
          5               25.00        3
```

In table 2 the OrderNumber is the foreign key that is able to join to table one. So your syntax would be:

```
    SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table2.OrderNumber = table1.OrderNumber
```

That will give you one table which you can read from.